# How can I replace a lamp post

Tags: lighting, outdoor

The lamp post at the corner of my driveway is perforated with rust. It appears to have come in two pieces as the top half is slightly smaller than the bottom and there is what looks like a reducing fitting at the midpoint. Other than that, it looks like most ~3" straight posts I've seen.

I dug down a bit and it seems like there's cement around the bottom of the post as if it was installed following http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/intro/0,,1531708,00.html.  I don't want to have to take out the whole footing.

It seems that with something like http://www.lightingdirect.com/kichler-9510-72-cast-aluminum-post-with-concrete-hardware/p1222544 I could dig out around the existing post, put sonotube in the hole, fill that with concrete, cut the old post off at the top of the concrete, and bolt the new post down.  Does make sense or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your approach should be fine, just make sure you get a good bond between the new concrete and the old otherwise it may spall.  just make sure your electrical line is in good shape.  otherwise you may go to all that work for naught.

Comment: I was relieved that the wire was in like-new condition.  I feared the previous home owner had cut corners and used wire that wasn't rated for exterior installation.

Answer (score 0):

I like your thinking & I agree that your plan should work out fine. However, If you have a Monkey Wrench or Large Channel-Locking pliers see if you can just slip the old post out or can 1/4-turn spin the post back & forth while lifting it out of the concrete to then install a replacement.

Some posts have a wire notch at the bottom & it might be locked in. But others, are flat bottomed & can pop right out.